# Dual boot Ubuntu Grub menu item duplication

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Ubuntu 22.04 (already updated/upgraded) enabled grub menu with customer entry, however when selecting the entry the grub menu blips for a moment and creates a duplicate of the said menu entry item. If I select the custom entry item 5 times, grub will create 5 new duplicate entries of the said menu entry item.

If I chose one of the duplicate the menu entry will run without issue, but that's a learning curve I want to remove.

The dual boot menu item is Batocera, installed on a separate volume which has a comprehensive walk-through and idiot proof code which runs a search to locate the boot and initrd files utilizing the Drive label.
I've switched from Drive label to UUID, but I am still getting the same behavior and I'm not sure why
Do I need to identify the second volume, partition and uuid as well?

yes permissions were updated to execute (sudo chmod +x /drive/location/folder for those learning or having the same issue) and had even gone so far as to grant ownership (sudo chown user:usergroup -R /drive/location/folder)

Could it be the search generating a result instead of loading as its usual behavior?

I've become so annoyed the a recreated the entire OS and added grub customizer as training wheels to ensure I am updating the config correctly, but the behavior persists.

System is an SBC 64 but grub behavior is not dictated by hardware.

Comment: Grub Customizer will add to confusion. It replaces grub with its own proxy files. Do not know details on proxy files. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Do not run any fix, as Customizer is installed. You could run a total reinstall of grub which erases Customizer & all your current settings.